# Simple (maybe antiquated) AS3 script stops after 30 seconds

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Designing some lessons in AS3 for the HS multimedia class  I teach.

I haven't tried to teach  this in my class in a few years, so I'm a bit rusty. It's also possible my script is not as smooth as it could be as I've based it on some AS2 work I did quite sometime ago.

That said, this little bit of code runs for about thirty seconds and then stops. No error, no feedback outside the trace command I put in to track array length.

This is part of a lesson series for getting the kids in the  direction of writing  some games in AS3. In this one we're looking at creating random timing and random placement. We've already covered motion, properties, variables,  listeners, and functions.

Here's the code:

```
import flash.events.Event;

var firstMeteor:Number = 1;
var timeSinceLast:Number = 0;
var lastMeteor:Number = 0;
var totalMeteors = 60;
var metProp=.08;
var rocksBox:Array = new Array;
var dropSpeed:Number = 15;
var lowLimit:Number = 350;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,dropRocks);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveRocks);

function dropRocks(e:Event):void{
    if(lastMeteor<totalMeteors) {
        if(Math.random() < metProp) {
            lastMeteor++;
            var rock:meteor = new meteor;
            addChild(rock);
            rocksBox.push(rock);
            rock.x = Math.random()*500;
            rock.y = 20;
            timeSinceLast = 0;
        }
    }
    timeSinceLast++;
}

function moveRocks(e:Event):void {
    for(var i:int = rocksBox.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        rocksBox[i].y += dropSpeed;
        if(rocksBox[i].y>lowLimit) {
            removeChild(rocksBox[i]);
            rocksBox.splice(i,1);
            trace(rocksBox.length);
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you drop a rock only when the total count of the `meteor`s created so far (i.e: the `lastMeteor`), has not yet reached the maximum amount of `totalMeteors` you specified! When it reached the maximum, then `if(lastMeteor<totalMeteors)` won't let any other "meteor" creation happen!!

Comment: Thanks! I need to remember to check all variables through trace to see what it tells me. This has been valuable and I appreciate your input.